# Find substr and copy the line

Tags: php, string

I use this to find all the files in a directory:

```
foreach (glob("mobilechatfiles/*.*") as $filename) {
echo $filename."<br />";
}
```

Result is something like:

```
userOne_userTwo.txt
userOne_userThree.txt
userTwo_userThree.txt
userFour_userOne.txt
userOne_userFive.txt
```

What I need to do is to search all the line for let's say string 'userOne' and copy everything (the file name) on that line. Can I do this with PHP?

Comment: `glob("mobilechatfiles/userOne*.*)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use strpos:

```
if (strpos($filename,'userOne') !== false) {
    echo $filename;
}
```

Comment: Such a big problem for me but such a simple solution. Thanks for fast response!